# A word to describe needed (and unobtained) stock?

Tags: single-word-requests

The term for stock needed that is already in possession is inventory. However, I don't know what to call the items that are outside the inventory that needs to be acquired.

What I want to do is keep track of the inventory (obviously), but also a list of items needed, that when obtained will be part of the inventory.

Comment: *Deficit*? *Shortfall*?

Comment: If you need them you are *short*.

Answer (score 1):

The technical  term that you probably need is:

***the (inventory/stock) replenishment*** :

> - an operation that consists in making the stock full again in order to avoid stock-out. [Replenishment](https://www.lokad.com/stock-replenishment-definition)is typically initiated by a backorder passed to a supplier or to a manufacturer.

Comment: Replenishment is just the operation though, I want a term to describe the to be obtained stock with which the operation would apply to :)

Comment: The is no specific one word for that. Stock shortage would generally be used to refer the the stock needed to go back to normal inventory levels. http://www.ncosc.net/sigdocs/sig_docs/documentation/policies_procedures/sigProcessing_Stock_Shortage_Condit.html

Comment: It depends on the circumstances. Replacing sold inventory with exact duplicates from a central warehouse is classical replenishment. Switching from spring to summer wardrobe is not replenishment. The replacement of an item having a limited time in inventory is handled by a planning function. You could call that *projected*. If approved for acquisition, *approved*, otherwise, you could call it *requested* or *estimated*. *Replenshments* used for the items themselves is common even if dictionaries have missed this. *Replenishment items*  might be more acceptable to the professional, though.